# Go binary size in comparison with c

Tags: c, go, compilation, binary

Yesterday I just wanted to compare simple golang `HelloWorld` app with c, go binary was something like `2-3 MB` (just `fmt.Println`) the equivalent c code, however, was just about 20 kb (`printf`). Then I checked system calls both binaries were doing, using `strace`; there was not a huge difference between both so do you have any idea why golang binary is so massive in comparison with c equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go binaries are, by default, statically linked, and also contain more information such as information about types that allows for reflection, type assertions, and so on. To quote the [Go FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#Why_is_my_trivial_program_such_a_large_binary):

> The linker in the gc toolchain creates statically-linked binaries by
> default. All Go binaries therefore include the Go runtime, along with
> the run-time type information necessary to support dynamic type
> checks, reflection, and even panic-time stack traces.
>
> A simple C "hello, world" program compiled and linked statically using
> gcc on Linux is around 750 kB, including an implementation of printf.
> An equivalent Go program using fmt.Printf weighs a couple of megabytes,
> but that includes more powerful run-time support and type and debugging
> information.

Comment: And the docs aren't update for later than go1.7, which compiles that program to around 1.4M (and ~1M if you link with `-w` and `-s`)